# Duplicate product/view tabs element in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, layout-update, products-view

I want to **duplicate the product/view tabs** element on the **product view page** in **Magento 2**.

I have copied the existing tabs layout data in `catalog_product_view` and duplicated it but only one instance of the block is shown on the product view page.

Can anyone please tell me how I get this working?